How to move an object and the armature together?
I have an object parented to an armature, I can pose the bones and the object moves correctly based on the bone movement, but when I just try to move the entire object to a different location in 3D space, I noticed that I actually have to manually shift-click on the object and it's armature in the Scene Collection tree so that the armature translates with the object when I press 'G' to move the entire thing to a different location in 3D space. I was assuming that if I moved an object in Object mode, that the parented armature would automatically move with the object, but is there something that I need to add or turn on so that when I simply click on the object in the 3D window, the associated armature will automatically translate along with the object? Thanks for your help.

You parented the mesh object to the armature. So the parent is the armature object, not the mesh object. And therefore it is normal that the armature object affects the mesh object, but not the other way around.
So you should move the armature object to move its children mesh object with it.
Ideally, you should even do that with a parent bone in pose mode, if this is supposed to be part of the animation.
